# How do you convert data from float64 to int16 in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, casting, floating-point, int, wav

Currently I am using `soundfile` to read audio data from a wav file like so:

```
import soundfile
raw_data, sample_rate = soundfile.read(filename)
```

Whilst I realise that you can select `dtype=int16`, I would like to know how to convert a float64 value to an int16 value (obviously there will be a loss of accuracy due to rounding, which is assumed to be acceptable).

Comment: @Reza Mousavi Rejected your edits as `whilst' and `realise' are both perfectly fine to be used in this way in British English. Both are dead in American English but alas... I am English

Comment: Sorry, It's my bad

Comment: That's ok, British English is strange :)

Answer (score 0):

`soundfile` depends on `numpy` so I assume you have that installed already, then you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# double-check your signal is in the range of -1..1
max_val = np.max(raw_data)
print(str(max_val))

# map to 16-bit
max_16bit = 2**15
raw_data = raw_data * max_16bit

# now change the data type
raw_data = raw_data.astype(np.int16)
```